# Pass selected option from dropdown into a variable using Adobe ColdFusion

Tags: forms, coldfusion, adobe, bind

I have a dropdown form from which the user selects from a list of query populated options (code blow).

```
<h3>Car Names</h3>
<cfquery name="carbrands" > 
SELECT *
FROM carcompany
WHERE cartype_id = 6
</cfquery>
<cfform name="mycars" action="?????.cfm"> 

<cfselect name="carbrandsearch" 
query="carbrands" 
value="car_name" 
display="car_name">
</cfselect>
```

I am looking to pass the users selected option into a variable so that I can pass that variable into other queries down the page.

I am not sure how to do this. I've heard mention of the bind function but I am not sure how to use it/if it is appropriate for this case.

Furthermore, I am not sure if I need to use the submit action because I am not really processing any of the data based on the selection(nor do I really want to navigate away from the page). I simply want to be able to pass the car name that the user selects into a variable.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: The simplest way is to submit the form to the current page and use some conditional logic to only run those other queries if the form variable exists.

Comment: *pass the users selected option ... into other queries down the page*  See this blog entry for an explanation of why that's not possible:  https://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html

Comment: Passing a user selection to the CF server requires a form submit, either manually (submit button) or with ajax.

Comment: Alright, I don't mind submitting to the page itself, but I've encountered a problem. The query in question above is in the mycars.cfm page which is within my views folder. However when I try to submit to the mycars.cfm file, I get  File not found: /views/mycars.cfm. Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you access that path in your browser, ie. http://yoursite/view/mycars.cfm? That said, if you're posting to the same page i.e. "mycars.cfm", action="mycars.cfm" should work just fine

Comment: No I cannot. It looks like this is a single page application with components being called depending on the option you choose. In this case would it be wise to send the post action to the same page everything else is being send to. Also, how would I do the processing in that case so that I can achieve the result in the main post? I am also open to using ajax if that would make things easier but am not sure on the best practice for converting form to Ajax/Javascript scripts.

Comment: Technically nothing wrong with a self-posting form, but a lot depends on the context. By "single page application" do you mean it's a simple app with one page or that you're using some sort of framework?