# Passing value from CFM to CFM for processing

Tags: coldfusion, adobe

So I have this code below. What it invokes is a query from the database which outputs all the brands of cars I have in the database. It then displays them in a dropdown list, hence this code below.

```
<h2>Car brand Option</h2>
<cfform name="mycarchoice" action="mainpage.cfm"> 
    <cfinvoke method="brandMatch" component="thecars.brand" returnvariable="getbrands">
    <cfselect name="mycarchoice.getbrands" 
    query="getbrands" 
    value="brand_name" 
    display="brand_name">
    </cfselect> 
    <br><input type="Submit" value="Submit" method="post">
</cfform>
```

I want to pass the users selected option to the mainpage.cfm so that I can do some processing on it. I have added mainpage.cfm as the action to be done when submit is pressed.

However, I don't know how to catch the value on my mainpage.cfm. What do I do/how do i start of so that I can write some code using what ever option my user selected from the code above as the input for whatever code I want to write on the mainpage.cfm.

Any examples would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: It's better to post a single question and update it with additional info, than posting multiple times about the same issue: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855933/pass-selected-option-from-dropdown-into-a-variable-using-adobe-coldfusion), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916020/converting-cfform-tag-into-javascript-using-jquery-adobe-coldfusion). See also [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - This becomes simpler if you change the name of your `cfselect` control so that it does not contain a period.  For the sake of this answer, we'll assume that you changed this:

```
<cfselect name="mycarchoice.getbrands"
```

to this:

```
<cfselect name="chosenbrand"
```

Step 2 - on mainpage.cfm, the users selection is available as a variable in the form scope.  It's name will be `form.chosenbrand`.  You can verify this by starting your mainpage.cfm with this code:

```
<cfoutput>
#form.chosenbrand#
</cfoutput>
<cfabort>
```

Once you know that the variable is there, you can process it as required.

Comment: I have tried the code format above using #form.chosenbrand# but when I refresh my mainpage.cfm I get the error:

getmatchLocations Element vendorMatch.getmatchLocations is undefined in FORM. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's outside the scope of this question but generally, if you refresh a page which was accessed by a form submission, you should be prompted to resend the data from the form.